# What should I do if I got decimal value in minimum support?

Tags: database, data-mining, apriori

I try to calculate some minimum support, with 30% minimum support count and also 4 transaction, the formula will be 30/100 * 4. After I count it, the answer is 1.2 which is a decimal number. I'm confuse about it, should I round it down or leave it on the decimal form?

Comment: Without more context this is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: "should I round it down or leave it on the decimal form" - that depends on the expected output